# PowerShell: Getting a "does not support user interaction" error when no input is required

Tags: powershell, team-foundation-server

I'm running a PowerShell script during a TFS 2015-based deployment. It won't run because PS thinks it needs user interaction, but, when I copy-and-paste the command and arguments into the PS console and call it directly, it works exactly as expected (with no user input).

Any suggestions? Thanks.

This is the top. I can't include more due to licensing reasons:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [String]
    $LocalDataPath, # .

    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [String]
    $ApiEndpointUrlPrefix, # http://hostname/ReportServer

    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [String]
    $DataSourceUrlRelPath = "Data Sources",

    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [String]
    $DatasetUrlRelPath = "Datasets",

    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [String]
    $ReportUrlRelPath = "Reports",

    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [String]
    $RootUrlAbsPath = "/Root"
)
```

Comment: Can you share the script?

Comment: @JamesReed Not the whole thing, but I've shared the parameter definition.

Comment: Post the script and the exact error if you want help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error is caused by some cmdlet or command in your script (showing the parameters is a red herring).

Look for `Write-Host`, `Remove-Item` et similia.

You can try executing your script passing the `-NonInteractive` flag to the Powershell interpreter or experiment different values for the `$ConfirmPreference` variable (e.g. `None`).

Comment: @GuilioVian Yes, I have many Write-Host calls. How does using Write-Host for output translate to PowerShell claiming that it needs user-input? When I run the exact same command by hand it runs without prompting the user for anything but when I run it as part of the deployment it terminates *immediately* with that error.

Comment: Powershell is an interpreter + a host app (e.g. console, ISE, your own), Write-Host cmdlet requires some host app interfaces.

Comment: That was *exactly* the issue. The merely presence of Write-Host caused console interpreter to demand TTY access.